# Best way to implement multi-language in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the best way to implement multi-language support in the Zend Framework?

I plan to use a separate language file for each language. Are there any other good approaches that I could look into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done it several times with Zend_Translate and poedit.

Check this links:

- [string-localization-with-gettext-and-zend-framework](http://www.tornstrand.com/2008/03/29/string-localization-with-gettext-and-zend-framework/)
- [internationalization-i18n-localization-l10n-15/using-poedit](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/internationalization-i18n-localization-l10n-15/using-poedit-671.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is ZF agnostic and IMO is the way to go.

Learn how to use [gettext](http://php.net/gettext) and use something like [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) to translate the content.